# Swift Sub Strings

Tags: swift, substring

Probably a very basic question, Im new to swift..

I am wanting to extract the hours from this string:

> Saturday, 11 July 2015 22:00

so the output in this case would be

> 22

Im assuming because the number of characters from the beginning would different I would have to work backwards?

any help much appreciated!

Comment: Lookup NSDateFormatter, NSDateComponents and related classes. Did you already read Apple's "Date and Time Programming Guide"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use component separate by string method:

```
var str = "Saturday, 11 July 2015 22:00"
var arr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").last!.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
var hour = arr.first!
```

It will work in this example but if you change the date format it could failed.
Much reliable option would be create NSDate object from the string and get hour component.

Comment: Your use of `!` is bad an you should feel bad.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity in the explanation I said what's the better way. If the string format change it won't work anyway but if you are sure that the format will be the same you can use !

Comment: It won’t “fail”, it will **crash**. Violently and immediately. Recommending this kind of technique – that will crash at the slightest whiff of bad input – really isn’t justifiable, especially not to people new to Swift and optionals.  It is not hard to write `if let hour = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").last?.componentsSeparatedByString(":").first { use hour }`

Comment: (if you still want it to trap during debug or even crash during production on bad data, you add an else section with an assert or fatalError)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I don't know the project requirement and sometimes it's better if the app crash. Maybe there is no point for the app to run if that data will be missing.

Comment: This is an advice/education website. Using `!` this way is bad advice/education. Once the developer has a deep understanding of optionals, it is possible (though unlikely) that `!` will be the right choice. But using it casually in an answer like this is **never** ok, as it gives people new to Swift the impression this is common idiomatic technique. It is not, it’s sloppy code. This is the reason there are 100 questions a day on here about why programs are crashing with “unexpected nil”.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use SubstringWithRange. It uses a start index and end index. You can change the two indexes in this to do what you want in this case.

```
var str = "Saturday,11 July 2015 22:00"
str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, 19), end: advance(str.endIndex, -3))) //"22"
```